# Retrieve user data on React + Redux + RTKQ application startup using persisted auth token

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

I'm creating an Electron Desktop App where I'm using React + Redux + RTKQ stack. When my application starts I'm loading persisted auth token to the Auth Redux Slice.

```js
const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
    [baseApi.reducerPath]: baseApi.reducer,
    auth: authReducer,
});

const rootReducer = (state: ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer>, action: AnyAction) => {
    if (action.type === userLoggedOut.type)
        return combinedReducer(undefined, { type: undefined });

    return combinedReducer(state, action);
};

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    preloadedState: loadAuthState(), // Here I load a persisted auth token <-------------------------
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(baseApi.middleware),
});

// Here I persist current state
store.subscribe(throttle(() => saveAuthState(store.getState() as RootState), 1000)); 

setupListeners(store.dispatch);

export { store };
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Now, If there is an auth token persisted in the auth state, I would like to call my RTKQuery endpoint to retrieve user details. I would like to display a splash or loading screen while the data is fetching because it doesn't make any sense to display any UI without any user data.

What is the best way to achieve this with this technology stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to put my user retrieving code into the `App` component inside `useEffect(..., [])` but I feel like it's not the ideal solution. Additionally, I check if auth token exists before running a query in my User API slice.

To avoid any unexpected consequences (e.g., I got into an infinite components refresh loop by accident) I store user data in a separate redux state slice and refer to it from all components instead of directly accessing data from rtkq query.

For the same reason, I introduced `isInitialLoadCompleted` const instead of relying on `isLoading` from the query as it was sometimes coming to `true` from `false` after some time when the initial load failed (documentation says it's only `true` for initial loads...).

###### App.tsx

```
export default () => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const [isInitialLoadCompleted, setIsInitialLoadCompleted] = useState(false);

    const [getUserQueryTrigger] = useLazyGetUserQuery();

    useEffect(() => {
        // Retrieve user on startup
        getUserQueryTrigger(undefined, false)
            .unwrap()
            .then(userResponse => dispatch(setAuthUser({ user: userResponse })))
            .catch(() => dispatch(userLoggedOut()))
            .finally(() => setIsInitialLoadCompleted(true));
    }, []);

    if (!isInitialLoadCompleted)
        return <SplashScreen />;

    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Outlet />
            <ToastContainer />
        </div>
    );
};
```

###### User API slice with auth token check before running the query

```js
export const extendedApi = baseApi.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: build => ({
        getUser: build.query<UserResponse, void>({
            queryFn: async (arg, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) => {
                const state = api.getState() as RootState;

                if (!state.auth.tokens)
                    return { error: { error: `UNAUTHORIZED`, status: `CUSTOM_ERROR` } };

                const result = await baseQuery(`/user/me`);

                // Everything below is mainly to satisfy the tsc.exe compiler, you can safely `return result` if using vanilla js
                if (result.error)
                    return { error: result.error };

                const baseResponseWithUser = result.data as BaseResponse<UserResponse>;

                if (!baseResponseWithUser.data)
                    return { error: { error: `UNKNOWN_ERROR`, status: `CUSTOM_ERROR` } };

                return { data: baseResponseWithUser.data };
            }
        }),
    }),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So I know this an old thread, but thought I'd throw in a solution that's worked for me. I came across this trying to see if my method is the route I want to take vs prefetching. I'm happy with this direction, though, and don't really see a need for prefetching for my particular use, yet. But what I did is I set up a listener in the store for dispatching my user credentials once they signed in. Then it fired off the api calls needed to load all the data. My api calls already pass back the auth token in the HTTP header. Here's my baseQueryWithReauth that checks for a refresh token in case the auth token is expired

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? 'https://api.artificertoolkit.app'
      : 'http://localhost:3500',
  credentials: 'include',
  prepareHeaders: async (headers, { getState }) => {
    const token = await getState().auth.token
    if (token) {
      console.log('token exists')
      headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    }
    return headers
  },
})

const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {

  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)

  if (result?.error?.status === 403) {
    console.log('sending refresh token')

    // Send refresh token to get new access token
    const refreshResult = await baseQuery('/auth/refresh', api, extraOptions)

    if (refreshResult?.data) {
      // Retry original query with new access token
      result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
    } else {
      if (refreshResult?.error?.status === 403) {
        refreshResult.error.data.message = 'Your login has expired.'
      }
      return refreshResult
    }
  }

  return result
}

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  tagTypes: ['Character', 'Spell', 'Builder', 'Feat', 'Race', 'Item', 'Class'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({}),
})
```

Then, my store looks like this

```
import { configureStore, createListenerMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { apiSlice } from './api/apiSlice'
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query'
import authReducer, { setCredentials } from '../features/auth/authSlice'
import deleteReducer from './deleteSlice'
import loadingReducer, { setLoading } from './loadingSlice'
import buildersReducer from '../features/builders/buildersSlice'
import { buildersApiSlice } from '../features/builders/buildersApiSlice'
import spellsReducer from '../features/spells/spellsSlice'
import { spellsApiSlice } from '../features/spells/spellsApiSlice'
import racesReducer from '../features/races/racesSlice'
import { racesApiSlice } from '../features/races/racesApiSlice'
import itemsReducer from '../features/items/itemsSlice'
import { itemsApiSlice } from '../features/items/itemsApiSlice'
import classesReducer from '../features/classes/classesSlice'
import { classesApiSlice } from '../features/classes/classesApiSlice'
import featsReducer from '../features/feats/featsSlice'
import { featsApiSlice } from '../features/feats/featsApiSlice'

const tokenListenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware()

tokenListenerMiddleware.startListening({
  actionCreator: setCredentials,
  effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {
    listenerApi.cancelActiveListeners()
    store.dispatch(setLoading(true))
    await store.dispatch(
      buildersApiSlice.endpoints.getBuilders.initiate(action.payload.id)
    )
    await store.dispatch(
      spellsApiSlice.endpoints.getSpells.initiate(action.payload.id)
    )
    await store.dispatch(
      racesApiSlice.endpoints.getRaces.initiate(action.payload.id)
    )
    await store.dispatch(
      itemsApiSlice.endpoints.getItems.initiate(action.payload.id)
    )
    await store.dispatch(
      classesApiSlice.endpoints.getClasses.initiate(action.payload.id)
    )
    await store.dispatch(
      featsApiSlice.endpoints.getFeats.initiate(action.payload.id)
    )
    store.dispatch(setLoading(false))
  },
})

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
    auth: authReducer,
    builders: buildersReducer,
    spells: spellsReducer,
    races: racesReducer,
    items: itemsReducer,
    classes: classesReducer,
    feats: featsReducer,
    delete: deleteReducer,
    loading: loadingReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware()
      .concat(apiSlice.middleware)
      .prepend(tokenListenerMiddleware.middleware),
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : true,
})

setupListeners(store.dispatch)
```

This is my authApiSlice

```
import { apiSlice } from '../../app/api/apiSlice'
import { setCredentials } from './authSlice'

export const authApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    register: builder.mutation({
      query: (credentials) => ({
        url: '/auth/register',
        method: 'POST',
        body: { ...credentials },
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(arg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled
          dispatch(setCredentials(data))
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      },
    }),
    login: builder.mutation({
      query: (credentials) => ({
        url: '/auth',
        method: 'POST',
        body: { ...credentials },
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(arg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled
          dispatch(setCredentials(data))
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      },
    }),
    sendLogout: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: '/auth/logout',
        method: 'POST',
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(arg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          await queryFulfilled
          setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(apiSlice.util.resetApiState())
          }, 1000)
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      },
    }),
    refresh: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: '/auth/refresh',
        method: 'GET',
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(arg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled
          dispatch(setCredentials(data))
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      },
    }),
    googleLogin: builder.mutation({
      query: (initialUserData) => ({
        url: '/auth/google',
        method: 'POST',
        body: { ...initialUserData },
      }),
    }),
  }),
})

export const {
  useRegisterMutation,
  useLoginMutation,
  useGoogleLoginMutation,
  useSendLogoutMutation,
  useRefreshMutation,
} = authApiSlice
```

What that does is set up a listener for the dispatch action of setting credentials, then it sets a global loading state to run my spinner as needed, and then gets all of the data. This puts it all in cache as needed for the rest of the application. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the idea with middleware, looks interesting. Unfortunately, I load the initial state from local storage, so there is no initial action dispatched for the middleware to catch.